# Does a motor really need all this circuit to run?

Tags: pcb, motor, battery-operated

This is the pcb of an Ikea screwdriver, you can see I desoldered the 18650 battery, from B+ and B-, and desoldered the motor from the legs of the switch which is on the other side. So the circuit should manage the charging of the battery and a couple of leds, other than the motor.

What I am thinking is, can I drive the motor directly from the battery and charge it with an external charger, or some of the parts are needed for the motor itself?

[image: pcb]

[image: other side - sorry for the weird perspective]

Comment: Reverse engineering of commercial products is highly instructive although it's got more difficult over the years as components shrink and more and more programmable devices appear. Try drawing out a schematic of the board and look up the data sheets for all the components you can identify. We'll tidy it up if you use the built-in schematic button on the editor toolbar. After that we'll start working out what the circuitry does.

Comment: Yes.  But on the positive side, at least they did not require you to assemble it before you used it!

Comment: How many leads are going to the motor? If it's just 2, try applying a small battery voltage to see if it will spin. If it's more than that, then chances are pretty good most, if not all, of that circuitry is "required".

Comment: If it's 3 wires going to the motor you can try an RC speed controller which are quite cheap.

Comment: First tip on the photos: Don't use your own crotch as the backdrop! :-)

Comment: @helloword922 it's only a positive and negative wire, the switch on the other side is used to inverse polarity I think. Does a motor need any protection or it just requires power? What if I wire it to an USB cable?

Comment: @DaveTweed changed the photos ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The motor does not need all that circuitry but the lithium ion battery needs all that circuitry to remain safe.

Running the motor directly from the battery is a bad idea. If a lithium ion cell is discharged lower than 2.5 Volts (typical spec) then the next time it is charged, it will get very hot and build up very high internal pressure. There is a high risk of explosion and fire at that point.

If it is charged to a higher voltage than specified, the battery can be damaged or become hazardous.

Lithium ion and lithium polymer batteries are much more dangerous than other rechargeable types. Thus they are always made with embedded electronics to prevent overcharge, overdischarge, and overcurrent conditions. If dangerous conditions are detected, the control IC opens an electronic switch to disconnect the cell from the circuit.

What you see there are safety circuits plus a charging controller IC. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is what I wanted to hear. Thank you very much!

So if I use a power bank like [this one](http://cdn.igeeksblog.com/wp-content/uploads/Vinsic-Tulip-iPhone-Power-Bank.jpg), and power the motor from the usb port of the power bank, it will work without problems? Can you confirm no protections are needed for the motor itself? Are all the components in there to protect the battery and make it charge and discharge correctly?

Comment: Yes, it would be much, much safer to power your motor from a USB rechargeable power bank like the ones you linked to because of the protection electronics they provide. This is as assuming it was designed properly, of course. Buy from a reputable source. Note that its USB output will be a bit above 5V, typically at up to 1 Amp max. Your motor will suddenly stop when the internal cell is depleted; it will not run slower as the battery depletes because the output is voltage regulated to 5V. Have fun tinkering!

Comment: I've made it and it works, but it looks like the power bank doesn't give enough power to the motor to run correctly. It runs a lot slower than what it did before, too slow. I think the traces on the power bank pcb are too small to draw current from...